# Cookies energy problem

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

On the package of cookies
Martino reads that the energy value of 100 grams of the
product is 400 kcal; moreover, a single cookie, whose
weight is 25 grams, contributes 5 percent to the
individual daily energy intake. It helps Martino to estimate
that energy requirement based on the information
listed on the package. How many cookies would be enough to
cover that requirement?

**Edit my attempt after the comment of @Gerry Myerson**:

If the energy value of $100$ grams of cookies is $400$ kcal and a single cookie weighs $25$ grams, we can calculate the energy intake of a single cookie as follows:

$$\text{Energy intake per cookie} = \frac{25}{100} \times 400 \, \text{kcal} = 100 \, \text{kcal}$$

Now, since the individual cookie contributes $5\%$ to the individual daily energy requirement, we can estimate the daily requirement as follows:

$$\text{Individual daily requirement} = \frac{\text{Energy intake per biscuit}}{0.05} = \frac{100}{0.05} = 2000 \, \text{kcal}$$

Thus, according to the information on the package, Martino would have an estimated daily energy requirement of $2000$ kcal. Each cookie contributes $100$ kcal, so the number of cookies needed per day to cover this requirement would be:

$$\text{Number of cookies needed} = \frac{\text{Individual daily requirement}}{\text{Energy intake per cookie}} = \frac{2000}{100} = 20 $$

> Is there another way to solve the question?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't say the daily requirement is 400 kcal; it says 100 grams gives 400 kcal. The textbook is correct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your advice. Change my attempt or remain this?

Comment: The best course of action is, if you see how to get the right answer, then write it up and post it as an answer. If you don't see how to get the right answer, edit the question to acknowledge your mistake, and rephrase the question to ask how to do it right.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done! I have understood. Is there another way to solve the question?

Comment: Yes. A single cookie is 5% of daily requirement, so 20 cookies are needed to make daily requirement. 20 cookies is 500 grams, 100 grams is 400 kcal, so 20 cookies is 2000 kcal, so that's the daily requirement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have not understood your logic of the problem. Please can you put a detailed answer?

Comment: OK, busy now, will get to it later.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok. Thanks.

Comment: "A single cookie is 5% of daily requirement" That's stated in the question. "So 20 cookies are needed to make the daily requirement" Because 20 times 5% is 100%. "20 cookies is 500 grams" because problem states a single cookie is 25 grams. "100 grams is 400 kcal" as stated in the question. "So 20 cookies is 2000 kcal" We've established 20 cookies is 500 grams, which is five times 100 grams, which is five times 400 kcal, which is 2000 kcal. "so that's the daily requirement" because we've established that 20 cookies makes the daily requirement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have understood now. Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeee.